# Regex Find/Replace Width and Height

Tags: html, regex, sublimetext3

I'm trying to run a find/replace on a series of files to remove the `width="..."` and `height="..."` definitions in SublimeText 3.

I've tried `width="*" height="*"` but I'm not getting any luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression pattern not matching anywhere in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string)

Comment: Are they always in that format `width="..." height="..."` ?

Comment: yes... example: width="122.198" height="95.21"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're matching `"` "zero or more" times by preceding it with the `*` operator. You can either use a non-greedy match in between `".*?"` or I'd prefer a negated character class `"[^"]*"`